# Box2D is hijacking the window resize listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, box2d

Here is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    resize();
    console.log('Resized');

});
```

This code was working perfectly fine until I implemented Box2D into my project.

Whenever I remove this line...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/Box2D.js"></script>
```

...The resize code works perfectly fine.

Any idea of what's going on? I'm using the [Box2DWeb](https://github.com/hecht-software/box2dweb) implementation btw.

Comment: Box2D shouldn't conflict with jQuery. Are there any errors in the [JavaScript error console](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors)? Are you sure that you actually have the Box2D file located in assets/lib? Have you referenced jQuery before or after referencing Box2D?

Comment: No errors in the console unfortunately. Physics and everything is running perfectly. Only problem is that for some reason the resize event doesn't fire when Box2D is included. And the Box2D file is indeed in assets/lib.

Comment: Then I can only assume that there is indeed a conflict between Box2D and jQuery in some way. Try swapping the order in which Box2D and jQuery are loaded, and also try loading a different version of jQuery to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it is still quite a mystery why Box2D is interfering with JQuery's resize function.

My temporary fix is to use the Javascript equivilent:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    resize();
    console.log('Resized');
};
```